# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Direct Update results in stuck Busy Indicator

Tags: android, android-emulator, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have a simple Worklight V6 app (no customizations other than `connectOnStartup` set to `true`) with an Android environment.

I start the app on my Android Emulator, make a trivial change to the HTML and re-deploy, and then restart the app on the emulator.

It notices that the app has an update, I click on update, the update happens and I can see on the screen that the app is now running with the latest HTML.

The problem is that there is a Busy Indicator in front of the app that never goes away. I have to kill the app and re-start it to access the app.

This seems to happen all the time on Android 4.3 and intermittently on 4.1.2.

Is there any code I can put into my app initialization to kill the busy indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *appears* to be the result of using the Android emulator configured to use the host GPU.  Reconfiguring the emulator to not use the host GPU either fixes the problem, or changes the timing enough to make it very unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of Worklight "v6" you use David, but testing with Worklight 6.0.0.20130926 (= 6.0.0.1 / 6.0 Fixpack 1), I have created a new project and application with the Android environment and connectOnStartup:true, ran in the Android Emulator (Android 4.3) and triggered a Direct Update.

The end result was - no stuck busy indicator...

Also, AFAIK there is no way for you to override the framework busy indicator that takes place on startup, other than setting the application to `connectOnStartup:false` and then for example invoking an adapter procedure request and handle the busy.show/hide() yourself in application-level code.

Try with 6.0.0.1 and above; It should be OK.

Comment: I just verified that I still see this in Worklight 6.1.  I created a fresh Android 4.3 AVD (using the intel/atom cpu) I created a new Worklight 6.1 App and changed connectonstartup to be true.  I ran the app on the emulator, updated the app in eclipse and redeployed, restarted the app on the emulator and … stuck busy indicator.  Just for grins I tried it in an Android 4.4 AVD (ARM CPU)  Same result.

Comment: Further testing and this seems to be linked with the AVD being set to Use Host GPU.  I can't reproduce the problem if I uncheck that box in the AVD editor.  It looks like that feature of the emulator is broken (or at least bent)  Pity, because it is one of the tricks to make the emulator less painfully slow.   In any case, this isn't looking like a Worklight issue so much as an Android Emulator issue

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter, can we resolve this either way? can you write an answer?